# Trying to remove the FALSE statement from Excel Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have rite a formula which is not a perfect one but is providing me the accurate result from the the data. There is just one problem in it that it also gives the FALSE value in the formula.

Which i want to remove If someone expert can do this i will appreciate the help or can provide the perfect formula that will be great help.

Please have a look on the below attached sheet.

Here is the formula

```
=IF(AND(C10<>$B$2,D10=7),"Y"&C10,IF(OR(D10=2,D10=5,D10=8,D10=11),IF($B$2=C10,"Q"&INT((D10-1)/3)+1&" "&C10),""))
```

and that False should not appear.

[image]

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1I3tGNecvQ7Kqt0bGDX1Rxdw2sveZuPddfUjE8I2ZzFM/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a blank condition for when the third if statement is false.

```
=IF(
    AND(C10<>$B$2,D10=7), 
    "Y"&C10,
    IF(
        OR(D10=2,D10=5,D10=8,D10=11),
        IF(
            $B$2=C10,
            "Q"&INT((D10-1)/3)+1 & " "&C10,
            ""
        ),
    ""
    )
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Chris Strickland I hope there can be an efficient way to do this. If yes then please provide if it doesn't bother you.

Comment: A little.  You can combine the second and third IF into one using AND and replace the OR condition with a MOD.  Take a look at the sheet now.  I put the formula in.  I don't know that it makes it easier to read or maintain, though.

Comment: Thank you very much that is great idea.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the false part of one of the IF statements, try this.

=IF(AND(C10<>$B$2,D10=7),"Y"&C10,IF(OR(D10=2,D10=5,D10=8,D10=11),IF($B$2=C10,"Q"&INT((D10-1)/3)+1&" "&C10,""),""))

Comment: Thank you very much I hope there can be an efficient way to do this. If yes then please provide if it doesn't bother you

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of "FALSE" you need to type `,""` after the last C10 in your formula.